# using external redis server for testing tcl scripts

Tags: linux, testing, redis, tcl

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

i am trying to run TCL test scripts using external redis server.

using the following :

```
sb@sb-laptop:~/Redis/redis$ tclsh tests/test_helper.tcl --host 192.168.1.130 --port 6379
```

Getting the following error :

```
    Testing unit/type/list
[exception]: Executing test client: couldn't open socket: connection refused.
couldn't open socket: connection refused
    while executing
"socket $server $port"
    (procedure "redis" line 2)
    invoked from within
"redis $::host $::port"
    (procedure "start_server" line 9)
    invoked from within
"start_server {tags {"protocol"}} {
    test "Handle an empty query" {
        reconnect
        r write "\r\n"
        r flush
        assert_equal "P..."
    (file "tests/unit/protocol.tcl" line 1)
    invoked from within
"source $path"
    (procedure "execute_tests" line 4)
    invoked from within
"execute_tests $data"
    (procedure "test_client_main" line 9)
    invoked from within
"test_client_main $::test_server_port "
```

the `redis.conf` is set to default binding, but it is commented out.

If this is possible, what i am doing wrong?

Additional Information:

Below is the tcl code that is responsible for starting the server

```
proc start_server {options {code undefined}} {
    # If we are runnign against an external server, we just push the
    # host/port pair in the stack the first time
    if {$::external} {
        if {[llength $::servers] == 0} {
            set srv {}
            dict set srv "host" $::host
            dict set srv "port" $::port
            set client [redis $::host $::port]
            dict set srv "client" $client
            $client select 9

            # append the server to the stack
            lappend ::servers $srv
        }
        uplevel 1 $code
        return
    }

    # setup defaults
    set baseconfig "default.conf"
    set overrides {}
    set tags {}

    # parse options
    foreach {option value} $options {
        switch $option {
            "config" {
                set baseconfig $value }
            "overrides" {
                set overrides $value }
            "tags" {
                set tags $value
                set ::tags [concat $::tags $value] }
            default {
                error "Unknown option $option" }
        }
    }

    set data [split [exec cat "tests/assets/$baseconfig"] "\n"]
    set config {}
    foreach line $data {
        if {[string length $line] > 0 && [string index $line 0] ne "#"} {
            set elements [split $line " "]
            set directive [lrange $elements 0 0]
            set arguments [lrange $elements 1 end]
            dict set config $directive $arguments
        }
    }

    # use a different directory every time a server is started
    dict set config dir [tmpdir server]

    # start every server on a different port
    set ::port [find_available_port [expr {$::port+1}]]
    dict set config port $::port

    # apply overrides from global space and arguments
    foreach {directive arguments} [concat $::global_overrides $overrides] {
        dict set config $directive $arguments
    }

    # write new configuration to temporary file
    set config_file [tmpfile redis.conf]
    set fp [open $config_file w+]
    foreach directive [dict keys $config] {
        puts -nonewline $fp "$directive "
        puts $fp [dict get $config $directive]
    }
    close $fp

    set stdout [format "%s/%s" [dict get $config "dir"] "stdout"]
    set stderr [format "%s/%s" [dict get $config "dir"] "stderr"]

    if {$::valgrind} {
        exec valgrind --suppressions=src/valgrind.sup src/redis-server $config_file > $stdout 2> $stderr &
    } else {
        exec src/redis-server $config_file > $stdout 2> $stderr &
    }

    # check that the server actually started
    # ugly but tries to be as fast as possible...
    set retrynum 100
    set serverisup 0

    if {$::verbose} {
        puts -nonewline "=== ($tags) Starting server ${::host}:${::port} "
    }

    after 10
    if {$code ne "undefined"} {
        while {[incr retrynum -1]} {
            catch {
                if {[ping_server $::host $::port]} {
                    set serverisup 1
                }
            }
            if {$serverisup} break
            after 50
        }
    } else {
        set serverisup 1
    }

    if {$::verbose} {
        puts ""
    }

    if {!$serverisup} {
        error_and_quit $config_file [exec cat $stderr]
    }

    # find out the pid
    while {![info exists pid]} {
        regexp {\[(\d+)\]} [exec cat $stdout] _ pid
        after 100
    }

    # setup properties to be able to initialize a client object
    set host $::host
    set port $::port
    if {[dict exists $config bind]} { set host [dict get $config bind] }
    if {[dict exists $config port]} { set port [dict get $config port] }

    # setup config dict
    dict set srv "config_file" $config_file
    dict set srv "config" $config
    dict set srv "pid" $pid
    dict set srv "host" $host
    dict set srv "port" $port
    dict set srv "stdout" $stdout
    dict set srv "stderr" $stderr

    # if a block of code is supplied, we wait for the server to become
    # available, create a client object and kill the server afterwards
    if {$code ne "undefined"} {
        set line [exec head -n1 $stdout]
        if {[string match {*already in use*} $line]} {
            error_and_quit $config_file $line
        }

        while 1 {
            # check that the server actually started and is ready for connections
            if {[exec cat $stdout | grep "ready to accept" | wc -l] > 0} {
                break
            }
            after 10
        }

        # append the server to the stack
        lappend ::servers $srv

        # connect client (after server dict is put on the stack)
        reconnect

        # execute provided block
        set num_tests $::num_tests
        if {[catch { uplevel 1 $code } error]} {
            set backtrace $::errorInfo

            # Kill the server without checking for leaks
            dict set srv "skipleaks" 1
            kill_server $srv

            # Print warnings from log
            puts [format "\nLogged warnings (pid %d):" [dict get $srv "pid"]]
            set warnings [warnings_from_file [dict get $srv "stdout"]]
            if {[string length $warnings] > 0} {
                puts "$warnings"
            } else {
                puts "(none)"
            }
            puts ""

            error $error $backtrace
        }

        # Don't do the leak check when no tests were run
        if {$num_tests == $::num_tests} {
            dict set srv "skipleaks" 1
        }

        # pop the server object
        set ::servers [lrange $::servers 0 end-1]

        set ::tags [lrange $::tags 0 end-[llength $tags]]
        kill_server $srv
    } else {
        set ::tags [lrange $::tags 0 end-[llength $tags]]
        set _ $srv
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either there's nothing listening on host `192.168.1.130`, port `6379` (well, at a guess) or your firewall configuration is blocking the connection. Impossible to say which, since all the code is *really* seeing is “the connection didn't work; something said ‘no’…”.

Comment: i have a redis-server running on port 6379. I am able to connect the redis-cli application to the same port.  I presume the port is open and accepting connection. If not how can i check this?

Comment: host `192.168.1.130` is my local wlan address. This is the Ip that is alloted to me. i tried with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`  but same result..

Comment: Well, _I_ would use `telnet thehost 6379` and see if it is doing the right thing. If it's web-based (or FTP) then `wget` can also be used.

Comment: yes i am able to telnet the host ... `sb@sb-laptop:~/Redis/redis$ telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
`  and  `sb@sb-laptop:~/Redis/redis$ telnet 192.168.1.130 6379
Trying 192.168.1.130...
Connected to 192.168.1.130.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: I am trying to point a tcl script to external running server. Whereas the script starts an instance of the server on its own and uses it, there is an option to provide external server in this script. Is there anything to do with rest of the params passed while invoking the server via the script?